# Android how to implement ZoomControls fucntions

Tags: android

I am new to Android, How to implement ZoomControls zoomIn & zoomOut fucntions.. please provide me with code to zoom in and out. Thanks

```
   private ZoomControls zoom;
   View v;

  zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //
}

}); 
zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //


}
});
```

Comment: Check this link : https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Comment: i don't want to zoom by touch because i have another actions to do with screen touch.. i want to zoom by buttons or controls

Answer (score 0):

Just go with the following 
http://sampleprogramz.com/android/zoomcontrols.php

you will get an idea about how to do this with **zoomcontrols**.

hope it will helps you.

Comment: i used this before and it doesn't work properly, yes it zoomz in but  i can't explore the view after zooming.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use this code for zoom in and out using buttons  
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ZoomControls zoom;
    ImageView img;
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    zoom = (ZoomControls)findViewById(R.id.zoomControls1);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float x = img.getScaleX();
            float y =img.getScaleY();
    img.setScaleX((float) (x+1));
    img.setScaleY((float) (y+1));
        }
    });
        zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                float x = img.getScaleX();
                float y =img.getScaleY();
        img.setScaleX((float) (x-1));
        img.setScaleY((float) (y-1));
            }
        });
        }
    }
```

Comment: i used this before and it doesn't work properly, yes it zoomz in but i can't explore the view after zooming

Comment: for that you have to use scrollview .